# Error: read ECONNRESET after application exit

Tags: react-native, expo

This question is specific to React Native Expo.

I get:

```
[09:50:39] events.js:167
[09:50:39]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[09:50:39]       ^
[09:50:39]
[09:50:39] Error: read ECONNRESET
[09:50:39]     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:139:27)
[09:50:39] Emitted 'error' event at:
[09:50:39]     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
[09:50:39]     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
[09:50:39]     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
```

The server crashes. This occurs a short time after exiting the app using the back button. Initially, I thought this was related to an audio stream that was played, but later I wrote a simple Hello World app and that produced the same result after exiting using the back button.

Is this the usual behavior, or could this be a side effect from the ESET firewall?

Comment: Can you please give more information about your problem. Like by server do you mean an API? Is this a release build? Are you trying to do run any background function? etc.

Comment: Have you tried disabling ESET firewall temporarily and check if the issue persists? Did you create the test app with `expo init`?

Comment: @bennygenel I was testing on Windows, this is the expo-cli I got from npm according to expo documentation, so I guess it's release build. I'm not really running anything at all, just a simple Hello World app (Just a View with Text), I created using expo init. By server, I mean part of the expo cli host environment (I think). After the error, the app cant reload. See also: https://forums.expo.io/t/error-read-econnreset-after-app-exit/17845, https://forums.expo.io/t/error-read-econnreset-after-audio-stream-playback/17547

Comment: @Siavas Yes, I used expo init. Just a simple Hello, World app (Just a View with Text). I now don't think  this has anything to do with ESET Firewall as others have reported the issue, even on Mac, but I'll check anyway.... After crashing, some part of the host environment seems to be still running and can be closed with Ctrl+C

Comment: Others have reported that the error also occurs when the phone display turns off, I haven't quite verified. I think, the error may also occur when the app is closed on iOS. I think a socket connection isn't being closed and cleaned up when the app fails to respond. Seemingly it times out and resets.

Comment: does it still happens after `npm i -S ws`?

Comment: ..or after disabling firewall?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I tried disabling the firewall, but still get the error. I didn't completely uninstall the firewall though, as it's part of the Antivirus. ws didn't seem to help either, though I don't understand how that could have worked anyway... I expect the expo cli doesn't use ws.

Comment: Yeah.. I had several problems with Expo at the point I abandoned that and used trial of Genymotion. It's paid, but I think it's totally worth it if you are going to use it for a long time.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was Fortinet Client. It is not simple to stop Fortinet Client. Check this one https://www.hongjun.sg/2014/12/how-to-stop-forticlient-from-starting.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not usual behaviour, and not sure if related to ESET firewall but a pretty common error. Lots of discussion here on [this expo-cli's github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/519) and potential fixes.

Exact cause hasn't been pinpointed but someone suggested that this seems to occur on Node v10, so if you have a node version manager ([using n](https://github.com/tj/n)) and switch to v8 while working with react native expo, it could rid you of this error.

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 8.16

// verify node version
$ node -v
```

(don't input $, this is in terminal, I'm on macOS)

Lots of people seem to experience this error, but not necessarily on app close, like me. For me on a good day, expo server might crash 1-5 times, or on a bad day, every 5-10 minutes. Super annoying.

Now I just switch to node v8.16 while working with react native expo and it's rock solid.